# Would drilling up magma be a viable method to obtain resources?

Tags: near-future, mining

Would drilling up magma be a viable method to obtain resources?

The way this drilling up of magma works is by drilling a hole 0.5-2 meters wide. Magma come up & once it is a few 100 meters below ground it is pulled into a large but shallow metal lined hole to cool into stone. After this the stone has holes drilled into it to be blown up into smaller chunks. After this the stone is refined into useable materials.

Would this method of mining magma be viable economically & physically? The technology level is near future.

Comment: Probably more economical to just cut rock from solid rock instead of all those extra steps. Not to mention the rate which the magma cools affect property of the stone

Comment: @HenryShao You don't get all the stuff that the magma contains from regular rock

Comment: One thing to bare in mind, magma is rather hot (up to 1200°C) so you'll need a metal that resists that extreme heat.

Comment: Star Wars's Mustafar would like a word.

Comment: What are you trying to get from magma, specifically? Example?

Comment: @HenryShao Lotta Metals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_mantle#Composition)

Comment: https://www.sciencefocus.com/planet-earth/can-magma-be-mined-for-ores-and-metals/ and https://www.quora.com/How-hard-would-it-be-to-extract-lava-from-a-magma-chamber for why this is not a good idea. @RaptorBricks already said that whatever you're going to use will probably soften.

Comment: What are you getting from the magma?  Most metal deposits, for example, are formed by steps that concentrate the element after the rock has become solid.

Comment: @JDługosz Lotta Metals (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_mantle#Composition)

Comment: I don't understand "Lotta" metals.  You linked to a composition that would indicate you're getting Oxygen, Silicon, and Magnesium, all of which are available in easier ways.

Comment: there's also iron, titanium & aluminium in there

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you about

## [Igneous rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igneous_rock)

> Igneous rock (derived from the Latin word ignis meaning fire), or magmatic rock, is one of the three main rock types, the others being sedimentary and metamorphic. Igneous rock is formed through the cooling and solidification of magma or lava.

---

> Igneous and metamorphic rocks make up 90–95% of the top 16 kilometres (9.9 mi) of the Earth's crust by volume. Igneous rocks form about 15% of the Earth's current land surface. Most of the Earth's oceanic crust is made of igneous rock.

---

> Igneous rocks are also geologically important because [ablist of scientific reasons and] in some special circumstances they host important mineral deposits (ores): for example, tungsten, tin, and uranium are commonly associated with granites and diorites, whereas ores of chromium and platinum are commonly associated with gabbros.

---

When the Earth was still solidifying, all the heavier elements sunk into the mantle. It was through volcanic eruptions that they made their way back onto the surface of the crust where they can be mined. So you see, we already drill a considerable amount of solidified magma without having to stick our drillheads into the hot stuff.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Much of the magma that reaches the surface via volcanoes on the continents is formed by melting continental rock. Drilling down is most likely to reach melted continental rock, not mantle rock. This rock will have a high silica content and lower rare element content. What you want is mantle rock.

The highest concentration of mantle rock comes from ocean bottoms. Instead of drilling, simply pull it up already on the surface and cool from the mid ocean ridge.

However, the concentrations of rare earth is still quite low. Where we are able to mine minerals, the rock was emplaced millions of years ago and fluid worked through the rock leaching out the minerals and then precipitating those minerals in cracks. Thus, gold is found in quartz filled cracks in the granite where the gold has been concentrated through the years. Without that fluid concentration, the percentage of minerals is so low as to be uneconomic to mine.

Even so, there are differences in the mantle magma so that some places have more gold, others have more silver, and some have more other minerals. We have no way of knowing up here on the surface where those concentrations are down there in the mantle melt.

Perhaps, there might be a way to find places on the mid ocean mountains where there is a concentration that might make it viable to mine. That is a future technology.

Comment: You could also try to mine the Columbia River Flood Basalts which is mantle material, but again, you have low concentrations of valuable material. The report at https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1982/0532/report.pdf has full chemical analysis. Most important minerals don't even show up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mining is not finding the wanted material, but finding it in concentration high enough to make it worthwhile extracting it.

When you quickly cool magma you are basically freezing a homogeneous mixture of different species, which you will have then to reheat and concentrate.

If you give enough time to the magma cooling aggregation might form, like it happens in granite, but we are talking about a number of years which is beyond the accepted range of "economically viable".